# How to save a webpage so that it can be reloaded and can be used again

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know whether this question is repeated (I searched a lot but couldn't find), if so sorry for that.

I have created a web page where users can create hierarchical diagrams by dragging and dropping components. After creating the diagram still those components are draggable and those components have option buttons also.

What I want is to save that diagram with all those features : which are created using javascript, so that it can be reloaded later and can be used.

If someone can help it is much appreciated!

Comment: We need more information about your code

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you make a hierachical object representation, stringify it into a JSON object and store that in the users Local Storage (or send it via AJAX to a server, where you store it into a database). Then you reload it from the Local Storage (or the server) and 'unpack' it from JSON to the object.

This means a fair amount of programmming, but I'm sure with this proposal you will have better search phrases to get a solution.

Comment: It was a broad question, so you get a broad answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For this type of webapp, you should use [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/). It provides a solid MVC structure that lets you represent your diagrams with Models. It also provides a framework to persist those models, either server side or client side (using localStorage).